# Hypothesis testing for choosing among a fixed number of hypotheses

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

In its most basic terms, suppose that I've got two different mutually-exclusive scenarios, $A$ and $B$, and that I know that, if $A$, then the probability of $C$ is 0.3, but, if $B$, the probability of $C$ is 0.6:

$P(C|A) = 0.30$

$P(C|B) = 0.60$

In actual testing of $n$ samples, $C$ happens 50% of the time, so

$P(C) = 0.50$

**Question**

Given $P(A)+P(B)=1$, what are $P(A)$ and $P(B)$?

As a real-world example, suppose a machine with two components is not always working correctly. If "component A" is defective, then the machine should fail 30% of the time. If "component B" is defective, then the machine should fail 60% of the time. After, say, 10 runs, the machine failed 50% of the time. What are the odds that the problem is with component A and the odds of component B?

I'm familiar with Z-, T-, and F-tests, but my understanding is that they only give you probabilities of *single* hypothetical cases. If I used them on two independent single cases (A and B), I'm not guaranteed that they'll sum to 1.

Comment: This is a Bayesian hypothesis testing problem.  You need prior probabilities $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ in order to get $P(A| C $happens 50% of the time from $n$ samples$)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data $D$ consists of 5 failures out of 10 runs. You know the probability of a single failure (given a single run) under each of your hypotheses. I'll assume that these hypotheses are independent, and that failures and successes are conditionally independent of each other (between runs). We want to compare the probabilities of the two hypotheses $A$ and $B$ given the data, i.e. $p(A|D)$ vs. $p(B|D)$. According to Bayes' theorem, we have:
$$
p(H|D)=\frac{p(D|H)p(H)}{p(D)}
$$
where $H$ is the hypothesis under consideration (i.e. A or B). So we first need to calculate the probability of the data under each hypothesis, i.e. $p(D|A)$ and $p(D|B)$. What you're describing is a series of random events with binary outcomes, with known probabilities. Therefore, the probability of a particular number of failures or successes follows a binomial distribution. In your example, we've observed 5 failures out of 10 runs. Therefore:
$$
p(D|A)=binom(5;10,0.3)\approx0.10
$$
$$
p(D|B)=binom(5;10,0.6)\approx0.20
$$
where $binom(x;n,p)$ is the binomial probability mass function for a series of $n$ events with $x$ positive outcomes, each with probability $p$ (note that I'm arbitrarily defining a failure as a positive outcome here, but you could work with successes instead if you use the complementary probabilities).

Next, we need to figure out the prior probabilities $p(H)$ and $p(D)$. We'll assume that the two hypotheses are equally likely *a priori*, since you didn't give any information to the contrary (i.e. $p(A)=p(B)=0.5$). To calculate $p(D)$ we can make use of the fact that $P(D)=p(D|A)p(A)+P(D|B)p(B)$. Filling this all into the equation for Bayes' theorem, we get:
$$
p(A|D) = \frac{p(D|A)p(A)}{p(D|A)p(A)+P(D|B)p(B)}
$$
$$
= \frac{0.1\times0.5}{0.1\times0.5+0.2\times0.5}=1/3
$$
If you repeat this for $p(B|D)$, you'll find that it comes out to $2/3$, as it should for the two probabilities to sum to 1. So given your data, the odds that B has failed vs. that A is to blame are 2:1.